# Ignoring first record in awk

Tags: awk

```
BEGIN{FS=","; t1 = 0; n = 0;  avg = 0; sum=0;  printf("%-10s %9s\n%-10s %9s","Name", "Average", "----", "-------") }

{
    if ($3 > 0){
        t1 += $3;
        n++;
    }
    sum = 0;
    if($3 > 0 && $4 > 0 && $5 >0){
        sum = $3 + $4 + $5;
        avg = sum / 3;
    }
    else if($3 < 0 && $4 > 0 && $5 >0){
            sum = $4 + $5;
        avg = sum / 2;
    }
    else if($3 > 0 && $4 < 0 && $5 >0){
        sum = $3 + $5;
        avg = sum / 2;
    }
    else if($3 < 0 && $4 > 0 && $5 < 0){
        sum = $3 + $4;
        avg = sum / 2;
    }

    printf("\n%-10s %7.2f", $1, avg);
}
END{
    printf("-------------------\nAverage for Test ! : %f.2", (t1/n));

    }
```

body part command should ignore the first record.

Comment: For me it's not clear what is the problem. Please add input file (or at least part of it) and the actual and expected output? If you just want to skip the first record and the script is not part of the issue, why do you add it in the first place instead of a minimal example?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by adding a test on the record number to your block:

```
NR > 1 {
    if ($3 > 0){
        t1 += $3;
        n++;
    }
    ...
```